# Unity - Raycast not hitting to BoxCollider2D objects

Tags: unity, collision-detection, raycasting

I'm working on 2D and I have a Quad as background.

[image]

And some wall sprites over this quad :

[image]

I'm instantiating wall prefab sprites over quad when user click to somewhere. But I don't want to instantiate a wall over another wall, so I'm sending a ray from camera to click point and if hit object is a **wall** object I won't instantiate.

Here my code :

```
RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity);
        // If it hits ground, not another objects (like walls)
        if(hit.transform.name == "GroundQuad") 
             Instantiate (wall, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity)
```

But it's still creating wall objects. Tried `Debug.Log()` to print hitted object's name to console and moved pointer all over game screen, it's always GroundQuad. So ray not hitting to wall objects.

Can you tell me what is I'm missing? Is it a problem with Layer Collision Matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out the problem. I was using `Physics.Raycast` instead of `Physics2D.Raycast` . Changed my code like this:

```
RaycastHit2D hit;
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector3.back);
        // If it hits ground, not another objects (like walls)
        if(hit.transform.name != "Wall") 
             Instantiate (wall, Input.mousePosition, Quaternion.identity)
```

Now it's detecting all collisions with objects **but** not detecting collision with Quad . You can send a comment if you know why it's not detecting quad.

Comment: Because Quad and its Mesh Collider belong to 3D physics.

Comment: So what you suggesting? Using Quad is bad idea for background?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use sprites for everything?

Comment: I'm tiling all quad surface with a little (32x32) grass image.

Comment: Then why not just think this way: unsuccessful ray-cast = no walls were hit = background was hit.

Comment: I'm thinking like that way but `if(hit.Equals(null))` always returning false and `if(hit.collider.Equals(null))` returning NullReferenceExceptions on quad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29169/discussion-between-maxim-kamalov-and-eray).

Comment: You're passing Vectle3.back (0, 0, -1) as a direction for the 2D raycast. This gets implicitly converted to a Vector2 by truncating the z component, meaning the ray direction is a zero vector. This will almost certainly lead to undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the normal Box Collider with your sprite ray cast will detect that.
I have also faced the same issue with this 2D Box Collider so i just used the normal box collider.

Performance wise its 2d collider only best but you dont get that much performance lag.